# HTTP requests in Chrome developers tools

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebug

In firebug when you send an ajax request from console, it will display the HTTP request in the console tab. This is not true for chrome. Is there any way to force console tab of Google Chrome to show HTTP request and response in the same way that Firebug does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chrome DevTools settings, you can enable the "Log XMLHttpRequests" option: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings#console

To display the information of your request, you have to click the URL of your request.

Florent

Answer (score 1):

Yep, `Chrome` too have developer tools, press `Ctrl+Shift+I` or via menu to open it, browse to  Network tab of it.

Comment: I think you did not read the question correctly. I reword it.